# Rspec error: location has already been taken

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have following test case in rspec

```
  let(:detail) { FactoryGirl.create(:detail) }

    let(:url) do
      "/detail/#{detail.detail_id}"\
      "/user/#{detail.user.id}/details"
    end
    let(:location_header) do
      detail_url(detail_id: detail.detail_id,
                  user: detail.user.id, location: detail.location)
    end

    before do
      post url, params: params
    end
    context 'when valid location and value are passed, detail is created successfully.' do
      let(:params) {{detail_app_id: detail.detail_app_id, location: detail.location, value: 'value'}}
        it { expect(response.status).to eq(201) }
    end
```

I am learning ruby rspec and i am getting an error "`{\"error\":\"Validation failed: location has already been taken\"}"`

when i change location value in params it passes but since i am creating factory girl for it i want to use that value rather passing different one.
Any idea why i am getting that error?

Comment: Please edit your answer to show the entire factory file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into one of your factories (I'm assuming detail) and assign its location properly (factories/detail.rb).

What's happening here is you're trying to create a new detail, which it attempts to save, but it fails the validation (I'm assuming you have a unique location validation on the detail model)

Check out http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md, the sequences section, for how to give a unique attribute where required.

Comment: Yes i have unique index on location and i have `    location { Faker::Lorem.paragraph } ` in factory girl.